# How to fill canvas text with variable sized circles with optimal performance?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I currently want to fill a given text (Actually... it's any image) with variable sized circles.

So far, I write text to a `<canvas>`, and then I get the image data with: `ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)`, and then I start looping through the array looking for pixels from the imageData.

I'm facing this problems, and I don't understand why :(

- It's way too slow (on large texts), how could I improve it's performance?
- Is there any algorithm that I could use that already exists so I can study it?
- If I use a bigger canvas to `getImageData()` from, the performance is so bad that it does not finish.

This is my code so far: http://codepen.io/Goodwine/pen/xDvLk

```
function circleCanvas(ctx, minR, maxR, padding) {
  var c = $('<canvas>')[0].getContext('2d');
  var img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  var h = c.canvas.height = img.height;
  var w = c.canvas.width = img.width;

  var ban = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < img.data.length; i += 4) {
    if (img.data[i] != 100 || isBanned(ban, i, w))
      continue;
    var r = parseInt((Math.random() * 10000) % (maxR - minR) + minR);
    var x = Math.floor(i % (w * 4) / 4) + r;
    var y = Math.floor(i / (w * 4)) + r;
    drawCircle(c, x, y, r);
    ban.push({xi: x - r - padding, yi: y - r - padding, xf: x + r + padding, yf: y + r + padding});
  }
  return c;
}
```

.

```
// this function is used because I didn't find how else to improve performance
// it checks if there is a point in a "banned" range, and it ignores it in
// case it does.
function isBanned(ban, p, w) {
  var x = Math.floor(p % (w * 4) / 4);
  var y = Math.floor(p / (w * 4));
  for (var i in ban) {
    if (x >= ban[i].xi && x <= ban[i].xf && y >= ban[i].yi && y <= ban[i].yf)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways you can optimize the code, as a start:

1. Add arcs to the path and fill at end instead of filling, setting color each time.
2. Use an `Uint32Arrays` to iterate and detect pixel
3. Replace the ban() regions with deltas to the counter

For example, you could add your circles this way:

```
function addCircle(ctx, x, y, r) {
  ctx.moveTo(x + r, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
}
```

Then iterate your loop using `Uint32Array`:

```
function circleCanvas(ctx, minR, maxR, padding) {

  var h = ctx.canvas.height;
  var w = ctx.canvas.width;
  var img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);

  /// use an Uint32 buffer instead
  var buffer = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);

  /// create new path here
  ctx.beginPath();

  var ban = [];  /// I'm ignoring this in this example
  var skipLines; 

  for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    if (buffer[i] === 0)
      continue;

    var r = (Math.random() * (maxR - minR) + minR)|0;
    var x = i % w;
    var y = Math.floor(i / w);

    addCircle(ctx, x, y, r);

    i += r * 2;
    if (x === 0) {
      skipLines = (r * 2 * Math.random() + r)|0;
      i += skipLines * w;
    }
  }

  /// fill at end
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fill();
}
```

**[See update here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpJsk)**

Comment: what is `skipLines` being used to in this example?
I've noticed that my `isBanned()` is WAY too slow and the bottleneck

Comment: OK, I think I've got it, the problem is that `for(var i in array)` is **too** slow, replacing it with `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` did the biggest performance solution, along with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The faster way to have text filled with random circles is to create a pattern with random circles, and just fillText with this pattern.
The pattern creation is quite fast, and must only be done once.
During a loop, just fillText with this pattern (no need to re-draw the circles).

I did a small demo, you can change the pattern or even animate, so you can see it is fast.

http://jsbin.com/oLIkAraJ/1/

[image]

Comment: I see, this is much better, however I want to do something related to getting circles in the above mentioned positions, I'll comment here by next week with what I mean by that.